# How do I find the contents of two functions with regex in python?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to search for the text between the ("") in a couple functions. I've been trying my hardest to figure this out, and I am sure it's something simple but I can't get it. I have the following...

```
search = re.findall('/(functionOne|functionTwo)\(\"(.*?)\"', text, re.MULTILINE)
```

But it always returns blank. If I use the code below, it returns all of the text within the quotes for the single function...

```
search = re.findall('functionOne\(\"(.*?)\"', text, re.MULTILINE)
```

Example input for this would be like so...

```
functionOne("I want this text", iDontWantThis);
functionTwo("I also want this text");
```

Example output for that would be...

```
I want this text
I also want this text
```

How can I get it to return all the text from both functionOne and functionTwo?

Comment: can you provide example input/output?

Comment: remove the leading `/` in your regex.

Comment: Example input would be...
    functionOne("I want this text", iDontWantThis);
    functionTwo("I also want this text");

Example output of that would be...
    I want this text
    I also want this text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the clarification, this should hopefully do what you want: It begins with a non-capturing or, looks for parens, searches soaks up everything until it hits quotes, grabs everything between the quotes, and makes sure it ends with a closing paren.

```
>>> buff = """
... functionOne("I want this text", iDontWantThis);
... functionTwo("I also want this text");"""
>>> re.findall("(?:functionOne|functionTwo)\(.*?\"(.*?)\".*?\)",buff)
['I want this text', 'I also want this text']
```

if you had a function call like this:

```
foo("hello, this is a very long
     string that needs to be less than
     80 characters", var1, var2)
```

You would need to use 're.S', to tell the '.' operator to include newline characters.

Comment: You are my savior. This worked perfect, thanks! Can you tell how much I hate regex? :)

Comment: They can be annoying, but I have to say, it's one of the single most useful things I've spent the time to learn.